# SQL query in Windows form with multiple variables

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, visual-studio-2010, combobox

been chasing my tail here for a while trying to figure out how to create a SQL query for a windows form that uses 4 parameters.
My form is connected via OLEDB to a VFP table. In my form I have 4 comboboxes, Item From, Item To, Date From, and Date To. My SQL query to fill a gridview is as follows:

```
SELECT `date`, descrip, item, id, itemtype, prodclass, loc, qty 
FROM kokfstut 
WHERE (item BETWEEN ? AND ?) AND (`date` BETWEEN ? AND ?)
```

This works great when all 4 comboboxes have values. Now I want to write the SQL query so that it will work if only the item range OR the date range have values. But if I write it as followed, I get an error because now it thinks there are more variables (8 instead of 4).

```
SELECT `date`, descrip, item, id, itemtype, prodclass, loc, qty 
FROM kokfstut 
WHERE ((item BETWEEN ? AND ?) AND (`date` BETWEEN ? AND ?)) 
   OR (item BETWEEN ? AND ?) OR (`date` BETWEEN ? AND ?)
```

So how can I achieve this with my 4 comboboxes?

Thanks for the help in advance,

Chris

Comment: Don't you just need this part? `(item BETWEEN ? AND ?) OR (date BETWEEN ? AND ?)` The first part of the WHERE clause is now redundant.

Comment: Each item has possibly multiple date values. So I want to be able to check for an exact item/date match which is why I have the AND statement.

Comment: Yes, but then you have an OR statement, and that will return true when only one condition is met (whereas your AND statement needs two conditions)... so the AND statement is redundant. AND will only be true when the other case is also true.... so you really just need the OR part... unless you are moving the variables around... can't really tell since they are all `?`

Comment: What I mean is, I'm reading that `WHERE` clause as equivalent of `WHERE (TRUE AND FALSE) OR TRUE OR FALSE`. Could be wrong though if you are moving around your 4 dates.

Answer (score 1):

You could just build your query dynamically:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append("SELECT * FROM myTable");

DateTime dateFrom;
DateTime dateTo;
bool validDate = DateTime.TryParse(dateFrom_cbo.Text, out dateFrom) && DateTime.TryParse(dateTo_cbo.Text, out dateTo);
if (validDate)
{
    sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@DateFrom", dateFrom);
    sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@DateTo", dateTo);
    sb.Append(" WHERE date BETWEEN @DateFrom AND @DateTo");
}

int itemFrom;
int itemTo;
bool validItemRange = int.TryParse(itemFrom_cbo.Text, out itemFrom) && DateTime.TryParse(itemTo_cbo.Text, out itemTo);
if (validItemRange)
{
    if (validDate)
        sb.Append(" AND ");
    else
        sb.Append(" WHERE ");

    sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@ItemFrom", itemFrom);
    sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@ItemTo", itemTo);
    sb.Append(" WHERE item BETWEEN @ItemFrom AND @ItemTo");
}
```

The logic with the WHERE and the AND placement is a little repetitive.  If you are doing this with more than two constraints then you might want to encapsulate them into a list of constraints (a list of strings) and then concatenate them at the end.

Comment: Trevor, I know this may be a pretty easy question, but how would I invoke this? Currently my query is in the tableAdapter and gets called when I press the "Generate" button with the following code: {
                 this.kokfstutTableAdapter.FillBy(this.dataSet1.kokfstut, comboBox1.Text, comboBox2.Text, ((System.DateTime)(System.Convert.ChangeType       (dateTimePicker3.Text, typeof(System.DateTime)))), ((System.DateTime)(System.Convert.ChangeType(dateTimePicker4.Text, typeof(System.DateTime))))); 
            }

Comment: My example was using the ADO.NET SqlConnection/SqlCommand.  There is an example here:  http://csharp-station.com/Tutorial/AdoDotNet/Lesson06

Comment: I'm also having trouble with the "sqlCmd.Parameters.Add", somehow missing a reference or a namespace. It will only let me use SqlCommand but then there is no Paramters.Add available.

Comment: Trevor, after a week of having the staff test the form it was decided not to use date parameters but to just look at dates in the future from the current date. I appreciate your help though and gave you a vote up. I never tested the code but am sure it would have worked. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Because you're using OLEDB, each ? will be a parameter by itself.

Either put all four parameters in, repeating values as needed, or you'll need to have the program check the combobox's contents, figure out which combination is relevant and run the appropriate query and parameters.